Calculating area of intersection of two segmented polygons in QGIS
I have two sets of polygons. One contains villages, the other farming areas.
There can be several farming areas in one village. Crucially, there can be cross-village farming areas.
My approach to get the area of all farming areas per village was this:

save both shapefiles in EPSG:3857 projection (pseudo-Mercator)
fix geometries
clip (farming areas to my villages)
intersection (to cut the farming areas by the village borders)
calculate the area in square meters via the attribute table ($area)
join attributes by location (summary) - the sum of the field square meters

Now, this is overall rather cumbersome. Is there an easier way to get to the result?
The problem: the resulting sum of areas is wrong.
In (6) I tried different types of intersection (intersect, overlap, contain), but none resulted in the equivalent to what I can add up manually?
Maybe somebody sees an obvious mistake here? Otherwise, I can try to upload data for testing.

Edit:
To further specify: The main issue for this case was that the villages are directly adjacent and farms can cross borders.


I did it to accelerate later processes. Farming areas cover a much wider area than my actual area of interest, as determined by the village layer.

You want a table with one row per village and a column with the sum of total farming area in that village?

That is correct.

Skipping the clipping step does not alter the results. They are still wrong.

I think an expression to perform the calculation like this should work, I have tested it and it seems fine.  area(
intersection($geometry,
aggregate(
layer:='yourfarminglayer'
,aggregate:='collect'
,expression:=$geometry)
)
)

When (within 1-6 above) and how do I apply this? Is this for the field calculator?

@kemajuan I have added an explanation as an answer - hope it makes sense

Note that Pseudo Mercator not a reliable CRS for measuring area

@Aquamarine, using the "$area" function, as stated in the procedure described in the question, the calculated area is ellipsoidal, so having the EPSG:3857 Pseudo Mercator CRS as the layer's CRS is not an issue.
On the contrary, using the "area" function as proposed by Sethinacan in their comment, will output the value of the area considerably different from the real area value if the layer's CRS is EPSG:3857.

Andrea Giudiceandrea - good to know - thanks

If you have many features QGIS processing tools will be fast.


My farms can overlap so I start with Dissolve (advanced option: keep disjoint features separate)
Intersect farms with villages
Field calculate an area field (decimal type) with the expression $area to calculate each intersection polygons area.
Statistics by categories:




Essentially, surprisingly and annoyingly, the command "join attributes by location (summary)" fails to deliver the right results in this use case. Your solution, @Bera, with "statistics by categories" works - thanks!

Nice. I suspect the join is creating duplicate rows

You can perform this calculation in an expression rather than using the sequence you have described.
Using your villages layer this expression will calculate the area of intersection you can use this in the attributes table or as a label if that helps for testing.
Note you need to change your layer name 'yourfarminlayer'
area(
    intersection($geometry,
        aggregate( 
            layer:='yourfarminlayer'
            ,aggregate:='collect'
            ,expression:=$geometry)
    )
)

The two interesting functions are:
intersection
Returns a geometry that represents the shared portion of two geometries.
you use this to do the intersecting
aggregate
Returns an aggregate value calculated using features from another layer.
this collects the geometry from your farming layer
You can also use this expression (omitting the area function) to draw the  intersection areas using a geometry generator in your villages layer.

When I start the calculation in the field calculator qgis turns into 'not responding' 'mode'. For half an hour this has not changed now. The reason might be that farming has about 370,000 features, 130,000 of which are within the 2,148 villages. The approach is not working out for me thus far.

I would test with a subset of your data

It works for a subset but remains unfeasible for my use case.

@kemajuan that's a shame, i'll leave the answer  as it may be good for others with a similar issue but less demanding data
